# How to create a login form with html/node js on MacOS

Tags: html, node.js

Let me start by saying I am working on a MacOS and I'm pretty noob in using it, but I'm also new in web development (mostly new in working with db connectivity, using Node Js). I'm currently having an offline webpage (not even set in apache, straight forward opening it in chrome) which has a login form. MySql server working, I have some data in MySql workbench. For start, I only want to ensure the connectivity, meaning I want it to automatically start the Node Js server when I press the Sign In button, and I want it to pop an alert saying something (later after, should be transformed in full login code). Here is the code in html and node.js. If anyone has any idea why it isn't working, please help. Thank you.

```
<button class="buttonn" style="margin-left: 20%" onclick="test()">
   <span class="text">Sign In</span>
</button>


<script>

  function test(){
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "yourpassword",
    database: "test"
    });

    con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    alert("Connected!");
    });
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Your code is NOT nodejs code. It looks like it comes straight from an HTML file. Javascript in the browser and javascript in node are not 100% the same. They can do different things in different situations. The browser has no access to the node API and node has no access to the browser API.

Comment: You need to take a few steps back. What you want is, a frontend that talks to a node rest API. The rest API will talk to the database and return the results to the frontend. Note, this is just one common way of doing it. There are of course countless ways.

Comment: @TheFool Thank you. I get it now! I think I know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run Node.js code *with Node.js* and **not** by putting it in a `<script>` element and trying to run it in a web browser.

Typically you'd type `node myScript.js` at the command prompt.

---

To run code in response to something happening in a browser you need:

- An *already running* server (typically you would write one that runs in Node.js using something like Express.js)
- The browser to make an HTTP request to that server (e.g. via a link, form submission or Ajax)

Comment: I will do that. Thank you!